# How to show the number pressed on a virtual keyboard in a QTextEdit box PYQT

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

How to show the number pressed on a virtual keyboard in a QTextEdit box? (PYQT)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
""" Prototype code for the infusion pump
code has to be updated """

""" Imports """
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys, time
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSize, SIGNAL

""" Globals """
global topTxt, midTxt, endTxt
global powerOpt, AlrmSil, bootC
global btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8,btn9
global btn0,btnDot,btnBK,btnClr,btnMain,btnChg,btnOpt,btnClrTot,btnPWR,btnAlrm,btnStrt,btnStop
global highVal, lowVal

highVal = 55
lowVal = 10
""" Globals Initialization"""
powerOpt = 0
AlrmSil = 0
class Infusion(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        """ Constructor """
        super(Infusion, self).__init__()        
        self.initKey()
        self.initText()
        self.showUI()


    def initKey(self):   
        """   This function initializes the buttons in the UI """ 
        global btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8,btn9
        global btn0,btnDot,btnBK,btnClr,btnMain,btnChg,btnOpt,btnClrTot,btnPWR,btnAlrm,btnStrt,btnStop
        btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton("1", self)
        btn1.setFixedWidth(30)
        btn1.move(650, 50)
        btn1.setEnabled(False)

        btn2 = QtGui.QPushButton("2", self)
        btn2.setFixedWidth(30)
        btn2.move(690, 50)
        btn2.setEnabled(False)

        btn3 = QtGui.QPushButton("3", self)
        btn3.setFixedWidth(30)
        btn3.move(730, 50)

        btn4 = QtGui.QPushButton("4", self)
        btn4.setFixedWidth(30)
        btn4.move(650, 100)

        btn5 = QtGui.QPushButton("5", self)
        btn5.setFixedWidth(30)
        btn5.move(690, 100)

        btn6 = QtGui.QPushButton("6", self)
        btn6.setFixedWidth(30)
        btn6.move(730, 100)

        btn7 = QtGui.QPushButton("7", self)
        btn7.setFixedWidth(30)
        btn7.move(650, 150)

        btn8 = QtGui.QPushButton("8", self)
        btn8.setFixedWidth(30)
        btn8.move(690, 150)

        btn9 = QtGui.QPushButton("9", self)
        btn9.setFixedWidth(30)
        btn9.move(730, 150)

        btnBK = QtGui.QPushButton("Back", self)
        btnBK.setFixedWidth(40)
        btnBK.move(650, 200)

        btn0 = QtGui.QPushButton("0", self)
        btn0.setFixedWidth(30)
        btn0.move(690, 200)

        btnDot = QtGui.QPushButton(".", self)
        btnDot.setFixedWidth(30)
        btnDot.move(730, 200)

        btnMain = QtGui.QPushButton("", self)
        btnMain.setFixedWidth(70)
        btnMain.move(60, 230)


        btn3.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)            
        btn4.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)
        btn5.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)            
        btn6.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)
        btn7.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)            
        btn8.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)
        btn9.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)            
        btn0.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)

        btnDot.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)
        btnBK.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)
        # btnClr.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)

        btnMain.clicked.connect(self.mainMenuClk)


        self.update()
    def initText(self):
        """ This portion initializes the Display of the UI, which is in black and green color """
        global topTxt, midTxt, endTxt


        midTxt = QtGui.QTextEdit("", self)
        midTxt.setFixedWidth(550)
        midTxt.setFixedHeight(100)
        midTxt.setReadOnly(True)
        midTxt.setStyleSheet('QTextEdit {background-color: #00FF00; color: black;}')
        midTxt.move(50, 80)
        midTxt.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)



    def showUI(self):
        """ everything initialized , now just show it """
        self.statusBar()        
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('InfusionUI')
        self.show()



    def digitClicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        self.emit(SIGNAL("sigKeyButtonClicked"), sender.text())
        print sender.text()







    def alignSecScreen(self,scrn, numScreen):
        global topTxt, midTxt, endTxt, btn1
        if numScreen == 2:
            midCsr = scrn.textCursor()
            midCsr.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
            self.midTxtInsert( 4 * ("\t"),8, "")

        elif numScreen == 3:
            midCsr = scrn.textCursor()
            midCsr.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
            self.midTxtInsert( 3 * ("\t"),8, "")

        elif numScreen == 4:            
            midCsr = scrn.textCursor()
            midCsr.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
            self.midTxtInsert( 2 * ("\t"),8, "")
        else:
            pass

    def mainMenuClk(self):
        """ Option 1 selection handler """
        global topTxt, midTxt, endTxt, btn1
        # topTxt.clear()
        midTxt.clear()
        # endTxt.clear()
        selection = 1
        self.midTxtInsert("\nMax:", 10, "")
        self.alignSecScreen(midTxt,2)
        self.midTxtInsert("59\n", 10, "")

        self.midTxtInsert("High:", 10, "")
        self.alignSecScreen(midTxt,2)
        self.midTxtInsert("%s\n"%highVal, 10, "")

        self.midTxtInsert("Low:\n", 10, "")  

        self.midTxtInsert("Min:\n", 10, "")  

        if(selection):
            sender = self.sender()
            selectionTxt = QtGui.QTextEdit("", self)
            selectionTxt.setFixedWidth(50)
            selectionTxt.setFixedHeight(30)
            # selectionTxt.setReadOnly(True)
            selectionTxt.setStyleSheet('QTextEdit {background-color: #000000; color: green;}')
            selectionTxt.move(500, 125)
            selectionTxt.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
            selectionTxt.show()
            selectionTxt.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


            cursor = selectionTxt.textCursor()
            textSelected = cursor.selectedText()
            # s = textSelected.upper()
            print textSelected
            selectionTxt.setText(textSelected)


            selectionTxt.update()
            self.update()



    def midTxtInsert(self, txt,font, algmt):
        """ UI is split to three region, this is mid part which is in green """
        global topTxt, midTxt, endTxt        
        midTxt.setFontPointSize(font)        
        if algmt.upper() == "C":
            midTxt.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        elif algmt.upper() == "R":
            midTxt.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        else:
            midTxt.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)  
        midTxt.insertPlainText(txt)
        self.update()         




def main():
    """ Function main """
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Infusion()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

adding a snippet here as i cannot share actual code, what i am trying is,

after clicking the left push button -> will get a black text edit box. i was trying to get the number entered to the box as and when numbers are pressed.

Comment: Place some code here. What a 'virtual keyboard' is?

Comment: updated the question with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
""" Prototype code for the infusion pump
code has to be updated """

""" Imports """
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys, time
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSize, SIGNAL, pyqtSignal

""" Globals """
global topTxt, midTxt, endTxt
global powerOpt, AlrmSil, bootC
global btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8,btn9
global btn0,btnDot,btnBK,btnClr,btnMain,btnChg,btnOpt,btnClrTot,btnPWR,btnAlrm,btnStrt,btnStop
global highVal, lowVal

highVal = 55
lowVal = 10
""" Globals Initialization"""
powerOpt = 0
AlrmSil = 0
class Infusion(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    sigTextButtonClicked = pyqtSignal(QtCore.QString)

    def __init__(self):
        """ Constructor """
        super(Infusion, self).__init__()
        self.initKey()
        self.initText()
        self.showUI()


    def initKey(self):
        """   This function initializes the buttons in the UI """
        global btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8,btn9
        global btn0,btnDot,btnBK,btnClr,btnMain,btnChg,btnOpt,btnClrTot,btnPWR,btnAlrm,btnStrt,btnStop
        btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton("1", self)
        btn1.setFixedWidth(30)
        btn1.move(650, 50)
        btn1.setEnabled(False)

        btn2 = QtGui.QPushButton("2", self)
        btn2.setFixedWidth(30)
        btn2.move(690, 50)
        btn2.setEnabled(False)

        btn3 = QtGui.QPushButton("3", self)
        btn3.setFixedWidth(30)
        btn3.move(730, 50)

        btn4 = QtGui.QPushButton("4", self)
        btn4.setFixedWidth(30)
        btn4.move(650, 100)

        btn5 = QtGui.QPushButton("5", self)
        btn5.setFixedWidth(30)
        btn5.move(690, 100)

        btn6 = QtGui.QPushButton("6", self)
        btn6.setFixedWidth(30)
        btn6.move(730, 100)

        btn7 = QtGui.QPushButton("7", self)
        btn7.setFixedWidth(30)
        btn7.move(650, 150)

        btn8 = QtGui.QPushButton("8", self)
        btn8.setFixedWidth(30)
        btn8.move(690, 150)

        btn9 = QtGui.QPushButton("9", self)
        btn9.setFixedWidth(30)
        btn9.move(730, 150)

        btnBK = QtGui.QPushButton("Back", self)
        btnBK.setFixedWidth(40)
        btnBK.move(650, 200)

        btn0 = QtGui.QPushButton("0", self)
        btn0.setFixedWidth(30)
        btn0.move(690, 200)

        btnDot = QtGui.QPushButton(".", self)
        btnDot.setFixedWidth(30)
        btnDot.move(730, 200)

        btnMain = QtGui.QPushButton("", self)
        btnMain.setFixedWidth(70)
        btnMain.move(60, 230)


        btn3.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)
        btn4.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)
        btn5.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)
        btn6.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)
        btn7.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)
        btn8.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)
        btn9.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)
        btn0.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)

        btnDot.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)
        btnBK.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)
        # btnClr.clicked.connect(self.digitClicked)

        btnMain.clicked.connect(self.mainMenuClk)


        self.update()
    def initText(self):
        """ This portion initializes the Display of the UI, which is in black and green color """
        global topTxt, midTxt, endTxt


        midTxt = QtGui.QTextEdit("", self)
        midTxt.setFixedWidth(550)
        midTxt.setFixedHeight(100)
        midTxt.setReadOnly(True)
        midTxt.setStyleSheet('QTextEdit {background-color: #00FF00; color: black;}')
        midTxt.move(50, 80)
        midTxt.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)



    def showUI(self):
        """ everything initialized , now just show it """
        self.statusBar()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('InfusionUI')
        self.show()



    def digitClicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        self.sigTextButtonClicked.emit(sender.text())
        print sender.text()







    def alignSecScreen(self,scrn, numScreen):
        global topTxt, midTxt, endTxt, btn1
        if numScreen == 2:
            midCsr = scrn.textCursor()
            midCsr.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
            self.midTxtInsert( 4 * ("\t"),8, "")

        elif numScreen == 3:
            midCsr = scrn.textCursor()
            midCsr.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
            self.midTxtInsert( 3 * ("\t"),8, "")

        elif numScreen == 4:
            midCsr = scrn.textCursor()
            midCsr.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
            self.midTxtInsert( 2 * ("\t"),8, "")
        else:
            pass

    def mainMenuClk(self):
        """ Option 1 selection handler """
        global topTxt, midTxt, endTxt, btn1
        # topTxt.clear()
        midTxt.clear()
        # endTxt.clear()
        selection = 1
        self.midTxtInsert("\nMax:", 10, "")
        self.alignSecScreen(midTxt,2)
        self.midTxtInsert("59\n", 10, "")

        self.midTxtInsert("High:", 10, "")
        self.alignSecScreen(midTxt,2)
        self.midTxtInsert("%s\n"%highVal, 10, "")

        self.midTxtInsert("Low:\n", 10, "")

        self.midTxtInsert("Min:\n", 10, "")

        if(selection):
            sender = self.sender()
            selectionTxt = QtGui.QTextEdit("", self)
            selectionTxt.setFixedWidth(50)
            selectionTxt.setFixedHeight(30)
            # selectionTxt.setReadOnly(True)
            selectionTxt.setStyleSheet('QTextEdit {background-color: #000000; color: green;}')
            selectionTxt.move(500, 125)
            selectionTxt.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
            selectionTxt.show()
            selectionTxt.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


            cursor = selectionTxt.textCursor()
            textSelected = cursor.selectedText()
            # s = textSelected.upper()
            print textSelected
            selectionTxt.setText(textSelected)

            self.sigTextButtonClicked.connect(selectionTxt.setText)
            selectionTxt.update()
            self.update()



    def midTxtInsert(self, txt,font, algmt):
        """ UI is split to three region, this is mid part which is in green """
        global topTxt, midTxt, endTxt
        midTxt.setFontPointSize(font)
        if algmt.upper() == "C":
            midTxt.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        elif algmt.upper() == "R":
            midTxt.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        else:
            midTxt.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        midTxt.insertPlainText(txt)
        self.update()




def main():
    """ Function main """
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Infusion()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and it works.

First, I define the signal     `sigTextButtonClicked = pyqtSignal(QtCore.QString)`,
then connect it to slot setText (you may want to define your own slot for to, for example, obtain multi-digit numbers in text field): `self.sigTextButtonClicked.connect(selectionTxt.setText)`

And I emit this signal every time digit was clicked:

```
def digitClicked(self):
    sender = self.sender()
    self.sigTextButtonClicked.emit(sender.text())
    print sender.text()
```

And take a look here, the syntax is pretty clear: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html

Comment: Perfect. Thank you :)

Comment: the self.sigTextButtonClicked.connect(selectionTxt.setText) will overwrite the existing text, what i was trying was like a calculator that keep appending. i tried (selectionTxt.append) but every time the text is ppended in new line.

Comment: append(QString) shouldn't append the new line, afais, just add some text to existing one.
But I think it'd be much better, if you define new slot for the whole widget (not just small black textbox), connect it to your signal, and do whatever you want in it. Then it'd be simple to implement multi-digit behaviour (and validation and whatever).
Moreover, you will then incapsulate the left widget behaviour and simplify program.